# How to configure Xtext mwe.Reader to fill the root element in a slot

Tags: xtext, xpand, mwe

*I am using Xtext 2.0 with MWE 1 and XPand, but I guess the Problem for MWE 2 and XTend is exactly the same.*

My Xtext grammer looks like this (excerpt):

```
grammer org.test.Test with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
generate test "http://www.test.org/test/Test

Model :
    "COMMON STUFF" 
    "{"
    (formatterDefs+=FormatterDef)*
    "}"
    ...

FormatterDef : "Formatter" name=ID  ":" formatter=STRING;
```

When I use this mwe definiton (excerpt):

```
<component class="org.eclipse.xtext.mwe.Reader" path="${project.src.directory}/xtext/model/" >      
    <register class="org.test.TestStandaloneSetup"/>        
<load slot='formatterDefs' type='FormatterDef'/>        
</component>

<component class="org.eclipse.xpand2.Generator">
    <metaModel class="org.eclipse.xtend.typesystem.emf.EmfRegistryMetaModel"/>
    <expand value="templates::Formatter::formatterTxt FOREACH formatterDefs"/>
</component>
```

So the slot `formatterDefs` is filled with all `FormaterDef`, and then this is used for the template, and every think works fine.

**But I have some templates that requires the model root element, named `Model` in the grammar. So I tryed to use**

```
<load slot='formatterDefs' type='FormatterDef'/>
```

and

```
<expand value="templates::Main::main FOREACH model"/>
```

instead.

But then I get this warning:

> **org.eclipse.xtext.mwe.SlotEntry  - Could not find any exported element of type 'Model' -> Slot 'model' is empty.**

And the slot contains an empty list.

So my Question is: **what do I need to do, to get the root `Model` into my templates?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant something like

```
public class MyDslNameProvider extends DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider {

    QualifiedName qualifiedName(Model m) {
        return QualifiedName.create(m.eResource().getURI().toString());
    }
}

public class MyDslRuntimeModule extends
                          org.xtext.example.mydsl.AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends IQualifiedNameProvider> bindIQualifiedNameProvider() {
        return MyDslNameProvider.class;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could customize the IQualifiedNameProvider to give the Model a name.

~Christian

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way is inserting the text `{Model}` just at the beginning of the rule, to ensure the creation.

Comment: That sounds interesting, I will try it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

A solution was to add an ID to the Grammer Definiton of the Model.

```
Model : name = ID
  "COMMON STUFF" 
  "{"
  (formatterDefs+=FormatterDef)*
  "}"
```

I understand that there was no existing Model element before, so after adding the ID the Model element must be created to contain the Id.

*How ever may there is a better solution - I will accept it, as soon as it is posted.*